# How to enable location services in Xamarin iOS App

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios, gps

I would like my simple to enable location services I have added the following in info.plist file

[image: Generic PList editor]

I have enabled background modes and location (ios Manifest Editor view)
[image]

However when i install the app (from XCode on a connected IPad - IPA). The app does popup a notification about allowing notifications however there is no message about enabling location services.

As per Ricardo's comment, I have added the required setting to my info.plist file. My info.plist file looks like this now.

[image: Generic XML Editor view.]

The only popup i get after building, reinstalling the ipa is allow notifications and no popup to allow location services. What am i missing?

Comment: you have to request them at runtime - see https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin

Answer (score 0):

It only ask when you start using location.
Alternatively you can force the app to prompt for user permission using Xamarin.Plugin.Permission package then check for permission and ask for it like this.

```
        var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Location);
        if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            if(await CrossPermissions.Current.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleAsync(Permission.Location))
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Need location", "Gunna need that location", "OK");
            }

            var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Location);
            status = results[Permission.Location];
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I am assuming the nuget package you are referring to is Plugins.Permissions from james montemagno. Sorry I am quite new to this, how to implement await DisplayAlert. Cheers.

Comment: `DisplayAlert` is a function in class that extend `ContentPage`. If you want to call it from other class, simply use `Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("...", " ", " ")`

Comment: Hi please forgive my ignorance, display alert seems to be unavailable in Xamarin ios.  What are the alternatives way of showing this alert? I tried UIAlertView and UIAlertController and i get error blah blah does not contain definition for 'GetAwaiter'

Comment: I have modified the display alert to UIAlertController without await and i can build my code fine however the if condition to show the alert is never true. What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

`NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` is deprecated ([Source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nslocationalwaysusagedescription)),

Use `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` instead.
Add this to your *info.plist*:

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your Message</string>
```

Comment: I already have this in my info.plist file

<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
 <string>Is it OK to track this device&apos;s location?</string>

I still do not get a alert asking for location.

Comment: @Abe i think that NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription is deprecated: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nslocationalwaysusagedescription

use NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription instead

Comment: i'm going to edit my anwser for better understanding

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I have added the setting you mentioned still not getting a popup. I have updated my questions with a screenshot of my info.plist file.

Comment: @Abe you are using Xamarin Forms with an iOS Project, or just Xamarin iOS?

Comment: @Abe and how are you trying to get the user location? because the problem might not be in the permissions, but in the way you are trying to acess the location

Comment: Disa Morias - I am using Xamarin iOS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194953/discussion-between-ricardo-dias-morais-and-abe).